# How can i access my parent li element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I can't figure out that how can I get the index of li whose checkbox is checked and add/remove the CSS class cut to that particular li.
I tried parent methods but that was not working maybe I was not doing in a proper manner!

for instance, I intentionally added the CSS cut class to the last li but I want to add this class to li when the checkbox is checked.

```js
function myfunction() {

}
```

```css
.cut {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#mylist {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="mylist">
    <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" class="status" onclick="myfunction()">
      <label class="mytodo">make tea</label>
    </li>
    <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" class="status" onclick="myfunction()">
      <label class="mytodo">notes making</label>
    </li>
    <li class="mycheck cut">
      <input type="checkbox" class="status" checked  onclick="myfunction()">
      <label class="mytodo">set clothes</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `this` keyword to the function so that you can identify the closest *li* element of the clicked checkbox:

```js
function myfunction(el){
  if(el.checked){
    el.closest('li').classList.add('cut');
  }
  else{
    el.closest('li').classList.remove('cut');
  }
}
```

```css
.cut{
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#mylist{list-style: none;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="mylist">

    <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" class="status" onclick="myfunction(this)" >
      <label class="mytodo">make tea</label>
    </li>

    <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" class="status" onclick="myfunction(this)">
      <label class="mytodo">notes making</label>
    </li>

    <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" class="status" onclick="myfunction(this)">
      <label class="mytodo">set clothes</label>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Attaching event using JavaScript:

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.mycheck .status');
checkboxes.forEach(function(chk){
  chk.addEventListener('click', function(){
    myfunction(this);
  });
})
function myfunction(el){
  if(el.checked){
    el.closest('li').classList.add('cut');
  }
  else{
    el.closest('li').classList.remove('cut');
  }
}
```

```css
.cut{
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#mylist{list-style: none;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="mylist">

    <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" class="status" >
      <label class="mytodo">make tea</label>
    </li>

    <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" class="status">
      <label class="mytodo">notes making</label>
    </li>

    <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" class="status">
      <label class="mytodo">set clothes</label>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: perfect.but can you please guide me how can i add similar event function if i want to add this through javascript ?

Comment: @WaniaRajput, if you want to attach the event using JavaScript then try the second answer:)