# How to add event listener for the elements that we create through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in javascript and i try to add some basic functionality here.
**kindly help me to write this function which acts when checkbox under li is checked!**
In this below code i want to add the class (cut) if the checkbox (under any li) is checked.
so a function will get the current li and apply class cut to that li.
i want to do this using event function but through java script.
also the cut class is applied to whole li not just label and checkbox.

```css
.cut{
  text-decoation:linethrough;
  opacity:.4;
}

#mylist{
list-style:none}
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">
            
            <li class="mycheck">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check">
                <label class="mytodo">make tea</label>
            </li>

            <li class="mycheck">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" >
                <label class="mytodo">notes making</label>
            </li>

            <li class="mycheck cut">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" checked >
                <label class="mytodo">set clothes</label>
            </li>


        </ul>
```

Comment: I think you asked this question before and already got a correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301363/how-can-i-access-my-parent-li-element-using-javascript

Comment: no both questions are different i am going to edit my title so that both may give different info.One is related to fix no of li having onclick function and this is related to how can we add events to the element that we dynamically creates through javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to avoid adding multiple event listeners if you can help it -- [reference here](https://gomakethings.com/checking-event-target-selectors-with-event-bubbling-in-vanilla-javascript/)

the code below adds a single event listener on the enclosing `ul#mylist` element and it places/removes the `.cut` class on the `li.mycheck` element as described in your question.

```
window.onload = () => {
    const list = document.getElementById('mylist')
    list.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // match is a checkbox?
    if (e.target.matches('.check')) {
      // if checked, get its parent .mycheck elm, either add or remove the cut class
      if (e.target.checked) {
        e.target.closest('.mycheck').classList.add('cut')
      } else e.target.closest('.mycheck').classList.remove('cut')
    }
  })
}
```

and below is the matching css for the cross-through effect

```css
.cut label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#mylist {
  list-style: none;
}
```

check out this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p69a7sgL/)

Comment: This is exactly what i need .

Answer (score 2):

Add an event listener to every checkbox.
When it changes, check if it's checked or not. Then, apply a class to the element with `elem.classList.add('cut')`. To remove a class you do `elem.classList.remove('cut')`.

I also changed your css to apply the desired effect of the line-through.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
 checkbox.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
   if(checkbox.checked){
     checkbox.classList.add('cut')
    }else{
     checkbox.classList.remove('cut')
    }
   
  })
})
```

```css
.cut {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.cut + label{
  opacity: 0.4;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#mylist {
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">

  <li class="mycheck">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    <label class="mytodo">make tea</label>
  </li>

  <li class="mycheck">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    <label class="mytodo">notes making</label>
  </li>

  <li class="mycheck cut">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" checked>
    <label class="mytodo">set clothes</label>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to every checkbox. You can get every checkbox with querying for it with [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) then from inside the "click" event when it happens you get the [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) `<li>` with the [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) function

```js
let allMyCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#mylist input[type="checkbox"]');
[...allMyCheckboxes].forEach( function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.closest('li').classList.add('cut');
    });
});
```

```css
.cut{
  text-decoation:linethrough;
  opacity:.4;
}

#mylist{
list-style:none}
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">
  <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check">
      <label class="mytodo">make tea</label>
  </li>
  <li class="mycheck">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" >
      <label class="mytodo">notes making</label>
  </li>
  <li class="mycheck cut">
      <input type="checkbox" class="check" checked >
      <label class="mytodo">set clothes</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```